# replacing domain names using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a new website as http://abc.com/case_studies/casstudy20/. 
I have an old website as http://xyz.com/clients/home.php?client=myclient

There are loads of case studies and stories under old domain that is xyz.com. Now that I am using abc.com is it possible to replace the URL, so it shows abc.com but access the code from the same old place.

meaning when my users goes to old site instead of xyz.com. It should say  http://abc.com/clients/home.php?client=myclient. But runs from the same old xyz.com.

Is it possible to do it using htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You can redirect all the traffic from xyz.com to the proper path on abc.com but this requires you to maintain control of both domains.

If you can, it's actually better to put this in the virtual host config for xyz.com then you don't need a complete configuration at all. Assuming you have permissions it will work in .htaccess as well though.

```
RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com$1
```

Comment: I have full control of both domains. I am new to htacess. It has got something to do with SEO thingy that if the domain name is different they are rated seprately. though they are the same sites. any-ways. All I was hoping was to mask xyz.com with abc.com. so I don't have to move the code and data from one domain to the other. And everything else remains the same.

Comment: Yes. The answer I provided gives you the ability to do that. You can do the same thing in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep control of both domains then you are looking for a http 301 redirect.  You can do that by adding the following line to your htaccess file to redirect an entire website. Without control of your original domain it's impossible for your old  xyz.com website to be routed to the appropriate server so your htaccess file will never have anything to redirect.

```
redirect 301 / http://abc.com/
```

Comment: This won't work if someone comes to the site using a full path. Consider http://xyz.com/some/path/to/a/case_study.html. See my answer using RedirectMatch